# Pytorch - Stack dimension must be exactly the same?

Tags: python-3.x, reshape, pytorch, tensor

In pytorch, given the tensors `a` of shape `(1X11)` and  `b` of shape `(1X11)`, `torch.stack((a,b),0)` would give me a tensor of shape `(2X11)`

However, when `a` is of shape `(2X11)` and `b` is of shape `(1X11)`, `torch.stack((a,b),0)` will raise an error cf. "the two tensor size must exactly be the same".

Because the two tensor are the output of a model (**gradient included**), I can't convert them to numpy to use `np.stack()` or `np.vstack()`.

Is there any possible solution for least GPU memory usage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you want to use [`torch.cat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) (concatenate tensors along an existing dimension) and not [`torch.stack()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack) (concatenate/stack tensors along a new dimension):

```python
import torch

a = torch.randn(1, 42, 1, 1)
b = torch.randn(1, 42, 1, 1)

ab = torch.stack((a, b), 0)
print(ab.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 1, 42, 1, 1])

ab = torch.cat((a, b), 0)
print(ab.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 42, 1, 1])
aab = torch.cat((a, ab), 0)
print(aab.shape)
# torch.Size([3, 42, 1, 1])
```